# tel:// not working in swiftUI, not redirection is working

Tags: redirect, swiftui

I have a contact number that should redirect to the user's dialpad, but that's not redirecting, I have checked with the real device still no correct response. What am I missing here? let me know in the comments how I improve this part.

```
Button(action: {
         if self.numberUrl != "" {
            let mobileURL = "tel://\(self.numberUrl)"
                guard let url = URL(string: mobileURL) else { return }
                     UIApplication.shared.open(url)
    }
          }) {
              Text(numberUrl)
                   .foregroundColor(.black)
                           .font(Font.custom("Comfortaa-Bold", size: 18))
   }
```